# Downloaded existing odt file not match with the actual odt file in PHP

Tags: php

I tried to download an existing odt file using the below PHP code.

```
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
      ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Pragma: public");   // required
    header("Expires: 0");       // no cache
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: private");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";");

    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
    readfile("$filename");
    exit();
```

When I executed, an odt file is downloaded, but the content is not as the original odt file content. That downloaded file contains something like serialized or non-readable text with multiple pages. Could anyone help me to get the actual file to download please?

Comment: _“That downloaded file contains something like serialized or non-readable text with multiple pages”_ – can you be more specific as to what that actually means? Multiple pages - of what? Are you calling that above code in a separate script file? Or is it part of a larger script, that maybe generates output before that point already?

Comment: When I opened the downloaded file, I got the below text instead of original text PK########n_XJ^Æ2 '###'#######mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.textPK########n_XJ################Configurations2/popupmenu/PK########n_XJ################Configurations2/menubar/PK########n_XJ################Configurations2/progressbar/PK########n_XJ################Configurations2/toolbar/PK########n_XJ################Configurations2/statusbar/PK########n_XJ#############.... The similar text repeated across all the pages

Comment: On which OS are you working? If on Linux then could you add the output of this command to the issue? `hd file.odt | head -n 10`  (for the downloaded file)

Comment: Or better: first and last 5 lines: `hd file.odt | head -n 5` and `hd file.odt | tail -n 5`  I bet that additional spaces/new lines are outputted before or after the file.

Comment: @Crouching Kitten, I am using windows

Comment: Then you could install a tool like HxD. Check if the downloaded file starts or ends with a space or newline. The PK at the beginning is not a problem, because the ODT is a compressed XML file in reality :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @CrouchingKitten. Will check.